Metadata-extractor - Hashing Image data - excluding exif tags
As per
How do I obtain a hash of the payload of a digital photo container, ideally in Java?
I've trying to create hash of a jpg (in csharp) ignoring the exif data.
So using the code in https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/tree/main/MetadataExtractor.Tools.JpegSegmentExtractor  I'm opening and pulling the SO1, DHT and DQT segments.
But what I've noticed after appending these 3 segments into one byte array, they only total about 540 bytes of a 4mb image.  So I must be missing something.   I also must be missing something because this hash finds a number of images.
public static (string,string) GetImageSha256(string file)
{
    try
    {

        System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file); 
        var segmentData = JpegSegmentReader.ReadSegments(new SequentialStreamReader(fileStream));
        var segmentByType = segmentData.ToLookup(s => s.Type);

        List<byte> imageData = new();

        foreach (var segmentGroup in segmentByType)
        {
            var segmentType = segmentGroup.Key;
            var segmentsOfType = segmentGroup.ToList();

            if (segmentsOfType.Count == 0)
                continue;

            var format = segmentsOfType.Count > 1 ? "{0}.{1}.{2}" : "{0}.{1}";

            var i = 0;
            
            foreach (var segment in segmentsOfType)
            {

                if (segmentType == JpegSegmentType.Soi || segmentType == JpegSegmentType.Sof0)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine($"Writing: Type: {segmentType} (offset {segment.Offset}, length {segment.Bytes.Length})");
                    imageData.AddRange(segment.Bytes);
                }
                else if (segmentType == JpegSegmentType.Dht)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine($"Writing: Type: {segmentType} (offset {segment.Offset}, length {segment.Bytes.Length})");
                    imageData.AddRange(segment.Bytes);
                }
                else if (segmentType == JpegSegmentType.Dqt)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine($"Writing: Type: {segmentType} (offset {segment.Offset}, length {segment.Bytes.Length})");
                    imageData.AddRange(segment.Bytes);
                }
                else if (segmentType == JpegSegmentType.Dri)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine($"Writing: Type: {segmentType} (offset {segment.Offset}, length {segment.Bytes.Length})");
                    imageData.AddRange(segment.Bytes);
                }
                else if (segmentType == JpegSegmentType.Eoi)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine($"Writing: Type: {segmentType} (offset {segment.Offset}, length {segment.Bytes.Length})");
                    imageData.AddRange(segment.Bytes);
                }

                //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new byte[], segment.Offset, segment.length);
            }
        }
        //segmentData = JpegSegmentReader.ReadSegments(fileStream);
        // Be sure it's positioned
        // o the beginning of the stream.
        fileStream.Position = 0;
        string ImageSha256 = BitConverter.ToString(System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(imageData.ToArray())).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        string Sha256 = BitConverter.ToString(System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(fileStream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {file} Sha256 Data {ImageSha256} Sha256 File {Sha256}");
        fileStream.Close();

        return (Sha256,ImageSha256);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
    return ("","");
}

